# Ubuntu-16.04 cannot get IP address

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet, intel

I just install a Ubuntu-16.04 64bit on a DELL T5810 box.
However its integrated NIC (`enp0s25`) cannot get IP address (I disabled IPv6 from grub).

Here is some reference information.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.0-78-generic (buildd@lgw01-11) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 05
       serial: 48:4d:7e:fb:21:4f
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7100000-f711ffff memory:f7139000-f7139fff ioport:f020(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enxec65dfc65da3
       serial: ec:65:df:c6:5d:a3
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=10.241.7.59 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s

$ ifconfig -a         
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:4d:7e:fb:21:4f  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6055 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:477671 (477.6 KB)  TX bytes:22490 (22.4 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7100000-f7120000 

enxec65dfc65da3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:65:df:c6:5d:a3  
          inet addr:10.241.7.59  Bcast:10.241.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:34383 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:44861383 (44.8 MB)  TX bytes:1621835 (1.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:298338 (298.3 KB)  TX bytes:298338 (298.3 KB)



$ sudo ethtool enp0s25
Settings for enp0s25:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: on (auto)
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Do you have any idea or advice?

====================Update 1==========================

I ever can capture the packets from this NIC using tcpdump

```
root@T5810b:~# tcpdump -ni enp0s25 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s25, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:40:22.283792 ARP, Request who-has 10.243.61.22 tell 10.243.61.1, length 46
11:40:22.285398 ARP, Request who-has 10.243.61.22 tell 10.243.61.1, length 46
11:40:22.348085 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 803d.5c:a4:8a:35:ca:00.8095, length 43
11:40:22.565028 IP 10.244.13.62.137 > 10.244.13.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
11:40:22.706688 IP 10.244.13.62.138 > 10.244.13.255.138: NBT UDP PACKET(138)
11:40:23.200992 IP6 fe80::e4f9:1574:ad7d:2108.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
11:40:23.272773 IP 10.244.13.49.58874 > 255.255.255.255.1947: UDP, length 40
11:40:23.315121 IP 10.244.13.62.137 > 10.244.13.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
11:40:23.503186 ARP, Request who-has 10.243.61.26 tell 10.243.61.1, length 46
11:40:23.507010 ARP, Request who-has 10.243.61.26 tell 10.243.61.1, length 46
11:40:24.311873 IP6 fe80::35d8:f19e:9a29:998d.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
11:40:24.345363 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 803d.5c:a4:8a:35:ca:00.8095, length 43
11:40:24.355285 IP6 fe80::197:e752:e5de:9d78.546 > ff02::1:2.547: dhcp6 solicit
```

====================Update 2==========================
Hello, David
    I re-check it with your script and edited some private information.
https://pastebin.com/Y1WujBgg
   Could you help to have a look?

====================Update 3==========================
To check and confirm the hardware and network infrastructure, I tried to install Ubuntu-12.04 and Ubuntu-14.04, both of them work -- their NIC eth0 can get IPv4 address by default installation.

Here is the Ubuntu-14.04's ifconfig output:

```
user@T5810b:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:4d:7e:fb:21:4f  
          inet addr:10.241.7.58  Bcast:10.241.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4a4d:7eff:fefb:214f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:54487740 (54.4 MB)  TX bytes:431458 (431.4 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7100000-f7120000
```

Comment: Thanks for your info. However you what you mentioned and linked is for wireless interface? my problem is for wired network -- integrated NIC.
If I misunderstand you, can you tell me that which commands I need to use?

Comment: Hello, David
   I did a diag check and put it here:
   https://pastebin.com/RiVeR8f7
   Could you help to have a look?

Comment: What is the interface `enxec65dfc65da3`? It appears to be connected.

Comment: It (enxec65dfc65da3) is one USB-ethernet converter, because I need to access this box remotely and temporarily.

Comment: Hello, David,
    I re-check it with your script and edited some private information.
https://pastebin.com/Y1WujBgg

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to proceed with that but I'm sure it'll somebody else to spot the issue.